# Codeigniter Load parameter to index in default controller based on URL parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to load a variable in the controller with the value that user enters in URL as a parameter eg: when user enters mysite.com/city1.

The default controller should be loaded and the variable should be set with city1. I have my index function in default controller (named as home) as

```
function index($location = ""){
 $this->load->view('header');
 $this->load->view('home_view', $this->viewData);
 $this->load->view('footer');
 }
```

I tried editing the condition of routes.php but it seems to be not working.I can access the index through mysite.com/home/index/city1
but I want it to be accessed through mysite.com/city1

Answer (score 2):

```
$route['home/(:any)'] = "home/index/$1";
```

Comment: Works fine.. but I would have to add mysite.com/home/city1
but i want only mysite.com/city1, if I change your routes condtion to

    $route['(:any)'] = "home/index/$1";
 then I cannot move to any other pages in my site. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Give mi some example urls because I can't understand the whole logic you're trying to implement

Comment: That's really cool, it works. But how to access the parameter that is passing to index function?

Answer (score 1):

uri class deals with what you need !

```
$this->uri->segment(n);
```

see here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html